# Tips on making apps faster

Tags: java, android, xml, performance

I have completed an app but its a bit slow moving through activities as most of it involve fetching data from firebase. I checked the [PerformanceTips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips) from Google and found out some ways on how to make it faster. I have a few doubts

Does declaring a variable Global affect speed? I know its better to declare it inside a class and not use Global unless its really needed but does it affect speed?Does it take up more space as that could be a problem?

Does Private or Public methods affect speed? If it does which is better?

Does having all methods in the onCreate affect speed? If I call some from the onStart will it make it faster?

I have a lot of methods and I call all of them in the onCreate. Is it better to write the code directly in the onCreate or group them as methods and call them instead?

As i mentioned most of it involved Firebase so which of the below type of code is better and faster

```
String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUID();
```

or

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String UID;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
UID = currentUser.getUID();
```

I also use

```
setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

and

```
keepSynced(true);
```

but still is slow. So any tips on making it faster is appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the actual code. Forget the variables and their declaration way. I would identify two problems by your words in `I have a lot of methods and I call all of them in the onCreate`, do you need to call all of this methods right in the `onCreate`? And  the second and bigger problem, what are those methods actually doing? If they are doing long computing tasks (like database access) try to do them asynchronically and let the app continue its job while you load all required data in background. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads

Comment: the scope of methods ordinary does not affect speed, however it may depend where fields are being held in classes and how they are being accessed; but that is milliseconds. as the question is written, this all is barely theoretical, hence it cannot be benchmarked or profiled. you might just run too much code on the UI thread, which causes an app to behave sluggish at times. one can offload the heavy tasks with `AsyncTask`. also see https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to profile your app to know what exactly are your performance issues. No two apps are equal. For example: calling multiple methods on the onCreate could have no impact or can make your app slow, **it depends on what you're doing on your methods**.

My recommendation to you is to check this google free course: https://eu.udacity.com/course/android-performance--ud825

**EDIT**

Check also the **Performance Pattern** series on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qk5F6Bxqhr4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Some performance topics that will have a significant impact on your app's performance:

1. Memory Leaks
2. Overdraw
3. View Hierarchy
4. Memory allocations

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

> I have completed an app but its a bit slow moving through activities
>   as most of it involve fetching data from firebase.

Let me give you an educated guess that global variables, private or public modifiers etc. will not really change much (or anything) if your actual problem is constantly talking to a database. You identified this as the part that slows you down, so this is the part you should optimize.

Comment: but declaring many Strings ints etc does take up more space and that inturn slows the app doesn't it?

Comment: @MichelleKinsten To take your code examples that you edited in: Both code snippets will probably be compiled to the same thing, so there is no difference. But if there was a difference - the database access takes way, way, WAY longer and costs more resources than a few declared variables. Where something like that can make a difference is when you create thousands, millions of objects. Then, of course also small things will add up over time. Don't worry about declaring variables and such micro-optimization when you are constantly talking to the database.

Comment: @MichelleKinsten What would help a lot more is use some memory to save, for example, the user ID so you don't have to look it up repeatedly in the DB.

Comment: Does declaring a lot of global variables affect anything? because i have a lot of global variables

Comment: @MichelleKinsten If you use lots of global variables, that is memory that your program is using no matter what. If you run out of memory then you will have the problem that the garbage collector runs frequently, which will manifest as your app being slow and eventually hang. But this happens only in the extreme. Just to say this again: If your DB accesses use 98% of the time (for example), then optimizing the 2% will not help you at all. Figure out what is slow about your app and optimize that.